# HTML 5 / File API - filter file type for file selection dialog on form

Tags: html, upload, filter

Did they add support for filtering file types in HTML5 or file API? I need to be able to filter images and documents only e.g. JPG GIF TIFF DOC PDF DOCX and no executable's or other file types. According to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#file-upload-state) HTML 5 same as HTML 4 can only filter AUDIO/VIDEO/IMAGE/EVERYTHING ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "accept" atribute like that

```
<input type="file" name="ufile" accept="audio/*" />
```